# Trying to read a file from html but getting undefined in nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, multer

```
app.post('/addimage', upload.single('image'), function(request, response){
console.log(request.body)
const body = request.file
console.log(body)
response.redirect('/image')
})
var storage = multer.memoryStorage()
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })




<div class="form-group">
    <label for="image">Choose a image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">
</div>
```

First is the nodejs code and second part is the html form. The request.body returns the image file name but when i do the request.file(s) its just undefined. Ive tried

Answer (score 1):

Solved needed to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form. Should have posted the full form for better help. Sorry